# jquery : Can I return back to same click event after user clicks on another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My requirement is to swap to widgets around. First time user clicks on widget A header, I can keep local info/data stored somewhere (i.e. 'user clicked widgetId=A') and now I wait for user to click on another widget header Widget B.

Once control passes back to original function Now I have info about Widget B id which I can swap.

```
<div>
<div class="widget header" id="WidgetA"> .... </div>
<div class="widget header" id="WidgetC"> .... </div>
<div class="widget header" id="WidgetB"> .... </div>
</div>
```

I have seen a jquery code on stackoverflow few weeks back which sends control back to earlier click event but since then I'm searching it and can not find anywhere.

something like -

```
$(..).on("click", function() {
   // some more code
    $(..).XXX("xxx", function(){
          //on second click code flows directly here...
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy/possible to "return back to the earlier click event" - instead, define a function that checks if both events have occurred, *something* like:

```
var widgetAclicked = false;
var widgetBclicked = false;

$("#WidgetA").click(function() { widgetAclicked = true; process(); }
$("#WidgetB").click(function() { widgetBclicked = true; process(); }

function process() {
    if (!widgetAclicked) return;
    if (!widgetBclicked) return;

    // process when both clicked
}
```

If you don't want to use `var`s for this, you can store on the widget itself, eg:

```
$("#WidgetA,#WidgetB").click(function { 
    $(this).data("beenclicked", true);
    process();
});

function process() {
    if ($("#WidgetA").data("beenclicked") != true 
            || $("#WidgetB").data("beenclicked") != true)
        return;
    // process
}
```

this also makes it easier to add/removed widgets without needing any extra code:

```
// apply to all widgets
$(".widget").click(function { 
    $(this).data("beenclicked", true);
    process();
});
```

then your `process()` can check which have been clicked for whatever nefarious processing it needs.

Comment: I have n number of widgets and user can click on any two of them one after other. I suppose if I check earlier clicks and swap two of the widget and remove 'beenclicked' it can work. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the clicked elements Ids in an array and the you will know which elements where clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var clickedElementsIds = [];

        $('#widget header').on('click' function(event){
            var clickedElementId = event.currentTarget.id;
            clickedElementsIds.push(clickedElementId);
        });
});
```

When you have the ids in the array you can then do whatever you wish with them.